# Rails Generate model error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a new RoR app and i had tried to create a new model like below.

```
rails generate model Pic title:string description:text
```

But I keep on getting these errors always and I tried installing many methods like installing gems ,updated the gems etc.

**P.S : I am trying install the older version of the gems. Is that creating a problem?**

But none of it gave me the results. Please help me with this.

[image]

P.P.S : I am an absolute beginner to ruby. So please help me by giving solution with good reason. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: run `bundle install` from the command line then try again. You put `simple_form` in your `Gemfile` but never bundled it with the application.

Comment: Also post your gemfile.

Comment: Adding to @engineersmnky's comment, the reason you have to run `bundle install` is because your app depends on gems, and you list them in the `Gemfile` to keep track of what they are, but listing them in the file does not automatically install them. They have to be installed by running the command `bundle install` which uses the `bundler` gem to parse your `Gemfile` and install any gems that you don't already have installed locally.

Comment: i ran 'bundle install' and they told me to run 'bundle update' . I also did that but still the problem exists.
P.S : I am trying install the older version of the gems. Is that creating a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@Navneet** pointed out generating a config file can also be used for configuration and it also works pretty well.

Another thing i found was , Here the gems used were older version. That created a **compatibility issue**(since it was not configured accordingly). So by replacing the gems with current version or stable ones , you can get rid of this problem.

1. Go to [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/)
2. Search for the gems and check whether its the latest version
3. If not, Replace the line of corresponding gem in `Gemfile` with newest one.

Answer (score 1):

Hi seems like you have issues with your simple_form gem,try to remove from gem file and add **gem 'simple_form'** and run **bundle install** after this step run **rails generate simple_form:install** for creating config file for simple form. 
Try this it may help you out.